# Unable to open URL in chrome on virtual machine using batch file

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have automated a flow using selenium webDriver. When I am running this using batch file from my system, it is running properly. But when tried to run the same batch from virtual machine, it is invoking browser but with blank URL. I am not able to run batch from virtual machine for Chrome driver.
Selenium Version: Selenium 3.4.0

I know, I am missing something but not able to find it.

Could anyone help me with solution.

Code inside batch:

```
start javaw -jar Example.jar
```

Thanks.

Comment: Who (as in Jenkins / TFS / etc) is starting the batch file? Does it work when you run it manually?

Comment: As of now, I am manually running batch file and getting this error.